# Is my answer to this PDE correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I know homework problems tend to be a bit unpopular on online forums, but I really need help with this problem since my college doesn't provide an answer to it. Also there seems to be no PDE Solver around on the web.

$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac {\partial u}{\partial t}  +\dfrac {\partial u}{\partial x}  +u=1 \\
u(x,0)=1
\end{cases}
$$

I've attached a pic [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z20M7.png) of the partial differential equation that I'm talking about, my answer and the PDE are marked in red.

A simple yes or no would be greatly appreciated as an answer, I'm not asking for a detailed solution since I want to figure it out on my own, I'd just like to know if my answer is correct.

Thanks so much in advance!

link to the picture:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z20M7.png

Comment: Please see here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/471959 how to write math

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I know about the MathJax commands, but I was under time pressure when I posted the question so I thought a picture of the work that I already completed will do the job. I'll stick to LaTex in future posts then :)

Comment: General solution $u(t,x)=1+e^{-t}v(x-t)$ should be easy using the found characteristics.